# NAN for correlation of random series in Matlab

Tags: correlation, matlab

I wanted to generate 2 uncorrelated signals by using Matlab but I am having strange results, probably due to my limited experience.

I know that there are functions `rand` and `randn`. If I generate these 2 by using `randn` the correlation of the 2 is always calculated and it is very low (as I was expecting).

```
z1 = randn(1,1000);
z2 = randn(1,1000);
corr(z1,z2) % it returns a very low number as expected
```

If I generate the 2 (or both) by using  `rand` like below the correlation is `NAN`.

```
z1 = rand(1,1000);
z2 = rand(1,1000);
corr(z1,z2) % it returns a matrix (instead of vector?!) of NAN
```

If I use again the 2 (or both) using  `rand` but this time generating a matrix instead of a vector it works and the correlation matrix is fine.

```
z1 = rand(1000);
z2 = rand(1000);
corr(z1,z2) % it returns a matrix of finite values
```

Do you know why in the second case (the one with NAN) I am returned

1. a matrix instead of a vector
2. why these are all NAN instead of a single finite value?

Comment: Minor suggestion: If you use `%` for comments people can more easily copy the code fragments.

Comment: Hi Dennis. You are right. I am using the wrong comment..instead the one for Matlab I am using the one for Visual Basic. Sorry about that. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, `corr` is expecting column vectors as inputs, corr(X,Y) returns a p1-by-p2 matrix containing the pairwise correlation coefficient between each pair of columns in the n-by-p1 and n-by-p2 matrices X and Y.
So, you were asking it to calculate the correlation on 1000 columns with only 1 observation per column! This is why you received a `NaN`.

Comment: This explains why a `NaN` appears in the second case, and makes sense for that --- but then wouldn't we also expect `NaN` to appear in the first case? Explaining why they're different in the two cases is kind of the issue here.

Comment: Actually the first one also returns a matrix of NaN. Probably the inputs were actually transposed, or the code was executed in a place where 'corr' is overloaded.